# iphone: how to check uitableview row modulus

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, modulus

it's a hard to explain issue so i hope i can state it

i have a tableview and i want that..

row number 1 have a background and row number 2 have another background .

and row number 3 have a third background..

the fourth row should have the first background and the fifth should have the second ..

and so forth ..

i used this code

```
if(row+1%1==0){
    bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row1.png"];
    selectionBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row1.png"];
}

else if(row+1%2==0){
    bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row2.png"];
    selectionBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row2.png"];
}else if(row+1%3==0){
    bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row3.png"];
    selectionBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row3.png"];
}
```

i'm trying to use modulus but i get lost .. so is there a way for that?

thanks in advance

Comment: ...that is now how modulus works... in any programming language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mod 3` because you have three options:

```
if (row % 3 == 0) {
    // Option A
} else if (row % 3 == 1) {
    // Option B
} else {
    // Option C
}
```

---

By the way, do you understand what a modulo operation does? This might be interesting to read (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)):

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder of division of
>   one number by another.
>
> Given two positive numbers, a (the dividend)
>   and n (the divisor), a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) can be
>   thought of as the remainder, on division of a by n. For instance, the
>   expression "5 mod 4" would evaluate to 1 because 5 divided by 4 leaves
>   a remainder of 1, while "9 mod 3" would evaluate to 0 because the
>   division of 9 by 3 leaves a remainder of 0; there is nothing to
>   subtract from 9 after multiplying 3 times 3.

---

This is what happens in the code:

```
row       row % 3   option
0         0         A
1         1         B
2         2         C
3         0         A
4         1         B
5         2         C
6         0         A
…         …         …
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the modulos use a static counter
Like the following

```
    static int rowBGSelector = 0;
    switch (rowBGSelector) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"%d, first", i); //Chose BG 1
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"%d, second", i); //Chose BG 2
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"%d, third", i); //Chose BG 3
            break;

        default:
            rowBGSelector = -1; //Reset the static
            break;
    }

    rowBGSelector++; //Increment
```